# Inverting functions containing ceiling

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, inverse, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I have a recurrence relation for a countably infinite sequence that contains the integers divisible by 5 but not by 7. The relation I came up with is:

$5((n-1) + \lceil \frac{n}{6} \rceil)$

The relation seems to hold. However, I wanted to try to solve for n to find the inverse.

Now, if this is in fact the correct relation for the countable sequence then it should be invertible since a countable set is a bijection. However, I do not know how to handle floor or ceiling functions when solving for n.

Can this be solved for n? If so, how is the ceiling function handled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:**

As $n$ is an integer, there are only 2 cases: $n=6k$ or $n=6k+c, 0<c<6$. For the first case, upper ceiling of $n/6$ is just $k$. While for another case, $k<n/6<k+1$,so it gives a value of $k+1$.